# Bluetooth SPP with multiple channels

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I would like to have multiple serial ports from DevA to DevB. The obvious way to do it would be to have DevB to advertise two SPP services on two different RFCOMM channels and with two different ServiceName. Right?

Alternatively I could have a single SPP instance with two RFCOMM channels. In order to do it, I would add one element to the ProtocolDescriptorList attribute in the SDP service record (see [SDP specification](https://www.bluetooth.org/docman/handlers/DownloadDoc.ashx?doc_id=260866&vId=290097) Table 6.1), namely:

`Protocol ID #2                                | UUID  | RFCOMM
     ProtocolSpecificParameter| Server Channel | Uint8 | N = server channel#`

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to have multiple serial ports from DevA to DevB. The
>   obvious way to do it would be to have DevB to advertise two SPP
>   services on two different RFCOMM channels and with two different
>   ServiceName. Right?

Yes you are right. except the ServiceName, you should define a different UUID compared with the normal SPP UUID then add it to SDP record database.

> Alternatively I could have a single SPP instance with two RFCOMM
>   channels. In order to do it, I would add one element to the
>   ProtocolDescriptorList attribute in the SDP service record (see SDP
>   specification Table 6.1), namely:

For most of the Bluetotoh stacks, their would be API named addSdpAttribute or addExtraUUID or whatever API, hence you just need call these API and then add the UUID, RFCOMM channel, and service name you mentioned.